# count empty char cells c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, isnullorempty

For goodness' sake, it's seems such a simple piece of code and I just can't figure out where I went wrong.

```
int count = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
    if (chararray[i]=='\0' && i == 0){
        cout << "Empty \n";
        break;
    }
    if (chararray[i]!='\0') {
        count = count ++;
    }
 }
cout << "Deleted " << count << "elements \n";
```

So the basic idea is that it goes through the array and if it's empty, then returns "Empty" and if not then it counts all the non empty cells and returns how many of them there were. If it makes any difference, I'm putting this under deconstructor method.

Generally it works fine, *it just won't COUNT right.* It either counts all or none.

---

UPDATE!

Thank you all! I removed the `count = count++` line with `++count` and it displayed more correct results than before, but not for all test values (and I promise not to make this same mistake again). As it is, I took the advice to use `strlen` function as there isn't a specific need for a 0 in place of, well, nothing. Also it made the code much, much shorter. Thank you!

Comment: How does `chararray` get populated? Did you explicitly set any characters to `'\0'`? Maybe parts of the array are uninitialized?

Comment: Have you look at `size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t maxlen)` ?

Comment: Switch `count = count ++;` for simply `count++;`.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what does this means "It either counts all or none"

Comment: @Cyber no I did not explicitly set any array value to '\0', I searched for solutions to empty value in char array and that was one of the equivalents to NULL offered.

Comment: Also @ravi I meant that it either gives back the size of the array or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You titled your question as

> count empty char cells c++

however as it is seen in the code snippet the count is increased when an element of the array is not equal to '\0'

```
if (chararray[i]!='\0') {
    count = count ++;
}
```

So what is the *empty char cell* that you are going to count?

Take into acccount that this statement

```
    count = count ++;
```

has undefined behaviour because applying the side effect of operaator ++ is not sequenced relative to the left operand assignment.

If the array contains a string and you want to know whether it is empty and how many characters in the string then you should use standard C function `strlen`

If the array does not contain a string and elements with value `'\0'` can be in any place of the array then that tp count non-zero elements you should use standard algorithm `std::count_if`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

//..

int n = std::count_if( chararray, chararray + 10, 
                       std::bind2nd( std::not_equal_to<char>(), '\0' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (chararray[i]=='\0' && i == 0){
```

This line looks for a null value and then checks if it is at index `0`
Try this:

```
if(chararray[i]==`\0`){
```

to break on the first null value and stop counting.

Also:

Please please please change this:

```
 if (chararray[i]!='\0') {
      count = count ++;
```

It is Undefined Behaviour (UB) and will very likely not be working as intended or break at some later point.

It should be:

```
if (chararray[i]!='\0') {
      count ++;
```

Comment: The code needs to test for the null char to stop counting, and *then* it should check if count is 0 and display its message accordingly.

Comment: Just put an `if (!count){std::cout<<"empty";} at the end then.  But yes, you're right, it that output is left where it is, it will print "empty" every time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  `chararray` has type `char []` you can simply use [***`std::count`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
auto num_items = std::count(  std::begin( chararray ),
                              std::end( chararray ), 
                              '\0' 
                            ); // returns 0 or number of occurrence
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem:

```
count = count ++;
```

is undefined behavior: it could result in something like...

```
tmp = count; // count == 0 
count++; 
count = tmp; // count == 0
```

or...

```
tmp = count; // count == 0
count = tmp;
count++;     // count == 1
```

Try `++count;` instead.